Give a Python class functionality to be interpreted as a Polars dtype?
Suppose I have:
from enum import Enum
import polars as pl
from typing import NamedTuple

Months = Enum(
    "MONTHS",
    [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec",
    ],
)

plMonths = pl.Enum([m.name for m in Months])

plYearMonth = pl.Struct({"year": int, "month": plMonths})


class YearMonth1(NamedTuple):
    year: int
    month: str


year_months1 = pl.Series(
    "year_months",
    [YearMonth1(2024, Months.Jan.name), YearMonth1(2024, Months.Feb.name)],
    dtype=plYearMonth,
)
print(f"{year_months1=}")


class YearMonth0(NamedTuple):
    year: int
    month: Months


year_months0 = pl.Series(
    "year_months",
    [YearMonth0(2024, Months.Jan), YearMonth0(2024, Months.Feb)],
    dtype=plYearMonth,
)
print(f"{year_months0=}")

year_months1=shape: (2,)
Series: 'year_months' [struct[2]]
[
    {2024,"Jan"}
    {2024,"Feb"}
]
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at crates/polars-core/src/chunked_array/ops/any_value.rs:124:75:
called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PanicException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 51
     43     month: Months
     46 year_months0 = pl.Series(
     47     "year_months",
     48     [YearMonth0(2024, Months.Jan), YearMonth0(2024, Months.Feb)],
     49     dtype=plYearMonth,
     50 )
---> 51 print(f"{year_months0=}")

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/series/series.py:641, in Series.__repr__(self)
    640 def __repr__(self) -> str:
--> 641     return self.__str__()

File ~/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/polars/series/series.py:637, in Series.__str__(self)
    636 def __str__(self) -> str:
--> 637     s_repr: str = self._s.as_str()
    638     return s_repr.replace("Series", f"{self.__class__.__name__}", 1)

PanicException: called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value

The crash occurs ostensibly because Months (the Python Enum) cannot be auto-converted to plMonths (the Polars Enum).
Is there any way to implement such auto-conversion either by:

extending Months with a method so that it can be auto-converted to plMonths
extending YearMonth0 with a method so that it can be auto-converted to as plYearMonth?


Easiest way would probably to just write an __init__ that does the conversion
